# How to make only two cells of UITableview selectable at a time in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

Is it possible to make only two cells of the UITableview selectable at a time? Currently i am only able to set single selection or multiple selection of the UITableView.

Please any one could post the idea or code in Swift3 for this?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell
    let currentItem = data[indexPath.row]
    if currentItem.selected {
      cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"check")!
      cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Bold", size:15)
    } else {
      cell.imageView!.image = nil
      cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Regular", size:15)
    }

    return cell
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the callback in `didSelectRowAtIndex` when a cell is selected. So you can to keep track of the selected cells and dis select cells accordingly. Use an array to keep track of all selected cells

```
var selectedIndexes = [Int]()


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row)) {
           selectedIndexes.remove(at: selectedIndexes.index(of: indexPath.row)!)
        } else {
            if selectedIndexes.count == 2 {
                selectedIndexes[0] = indexPath.row
            } else {
                selectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)
            }

        }
        tableView.reloadData()
}

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell
    let currentItem = data[indexPath.row]
    if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row) {
      cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"check")!
      cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Bold", size:15)
    } else {
      cell.imageView!.image = nil
      cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Regular", size:15)
    }

    return cell
  }
```

Comment: how to do this??

Comment: it is showing "Type int has no member contains" error

Comment: I'm sorry there was a mistake declare selectedIndexes as var selectedIndexes = [Int]()